# reconciliation and approval using smart contract

Tags: contract-development

Has anyone attempt to build smart contracts for reconciliation and approval workflows/process?

E.g., if fields match, update the string variable and evoke another contract to request for approval

Nathan Aw

Comment: It might be helpful to be more specific because almost all useful contracts fit this description. For example, escrow, games, crowd funding, all use some set of rules to check conditions leading to something that happens.

Answer (score 1):

I find the following pattern can be used quite easily for interacting with different contracts. Using interfaces allows you to easily specify the function signatures for different contracts so that your contract knows how to talk to other ones.

```
interface TestInterface {
    function someAction() external returns (bool);
}

contract SomeContract {
    TestInterface public tI = TestInterface(address(0));

    function someFunc(string _someString) public returns (bool) {
        if (keccak256(_someString) == keccak256("hello")) {
            require(tI.someAction());
        }
    }
}
```

Links:

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#interfaces

https://zupzup.org/smart-contract-interaction/